# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4 Process: com.hikvision.open.app, PID: 20137

Tags: java, android

I want to make an app to get the video from a web camera, but there is an exception. The tool which I used is Android Studio.

The link that download project:
https://pan.baidu.com/s/1C0NGT73Ct0wfzQYoYUW5JQ

> EXCEPTION: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
>       Process: com.hikvision.open.app, PID: 20137
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method (Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;)V in class
>   Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar:classes3.dex)
>           at com.hikvision.artemis.sdk.util.HttpUtil.sslClient(HttpUtil.java:499)
>           at com.hikvision.artemis.sdk.util.HttpUtil.wrapClient(HttpUtil.java:478)
>           at com.hikvision.artemis.sdk.util.HttpUtil.httpPost(HttpUtil.java:178)
>           at com.hikvision.artemis.sdk.Client.execute(Client.java:53)
>           at com.hikvision.artemis.sdk.ArtemisHttpUtil.doPostStringArtemis(ArtemisHttpUtil.java:182)

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.preview_button) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, PreviewActivity.class));
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.find_button) {
        String stringhost = host.getText().toString().trim();
        String stringkey = key.getText().toString().trim();
        String stringsecret = secret.getText().toString().trim();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(stringhost)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "所输内容为空，请确认后输入", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(stringkey)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "所输内容为空，请确认后输入", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(stringsecret)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "所输内容为空，请确认后输入", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                ArtemisConfig.host = stringhost;//"127.0.0.1:443"; // artemis网关服务器ip端口
                ArtemisConfig.appKey = stringkey;//"29180881";  // 秘钥appkey
                ArtemisConfig.appSecret = stringsecret;//"XO0wCAYGi4KV70ybjznx";// 秘钥appSecret

                /**
                 * STEP2：设置OpenAPI接口的上下文
                 */
                final String ARTEMIS_PATH = "/artemis";

                /**
                 * STEP3：设置接口的URI地址
                 */
                final String VechicleDataApi = ARTEMIS_PATH +"/api/fms/v3/human/findSnapHuman";
                Map<String,String> path = new HashMap<String,String>(2){
                    {
                        put("https://",VechicleDataApi);
                    }
                };

                /**
                 * STEP4：设置参数提交方式
                 */
                //String contentType = "application/json";

                /**
                 * STEP5：组装请求参数
                 */
                JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                try{
                    jsonBody.put("deviceCodes","-1");
                    jsonBody.put("sex",-1);
                    jsonBody.put("beginDate","2017-09-01 12:00:00");
                    jsonBody.put("endDate","2017-09-12 12:00:00");
                    jsonBody.put("similarityMin",0.1);
                    jsonBody.put("similarityMax",1);
                    jsonBody.put("picUrl", "http://10.33.44.61:6501/pic?=d82i649e*4ebi05f-646618-52c3ca0764e4cai5b1*=1d6s4*=6dpi*=1d3i4t2pe*m5i13=-1050e3-10z1cas=630bd1");
                    jsonBody.put("pageNo",1);
                    jsonBody.put("pageSize",12);
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Message message = Message.obtain();
                    message.what = ERROR;
                }
                String body = jsonBody.toString();
                /**
                 * STEP6：调用接口
                 */
                String result = ArtemisHttpUtil.doPostStringArtemis(path,body,null,null,"application/json");// post请求application/json类型参数
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.what = SUCCESS;
                message.obj = result;
                FindURL fi = new FindURL();
                fi.setUrl(result);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hikvision.open.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.blankj:utilcode:1.20.3'
    implementation files('libs/artemis-http-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}
```

When I use runOnUiThread to instead of the handler,the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button mPreviewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.preview_button);
    mPreviewButton.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    Button mfindButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.find_button);
    mfindButton.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    requestPermissions();

    host = findViewById(R.id.text_input_host);
    key = findViewById(R.id.text_input_key);
    secret = findViewById(R.id.text_input_secret);

    Toast.makeText(this, "请先获得地址，之后实时预览", LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.preview_button) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, PreviewActivity.class));
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.find_button) {
        String stringhost = host.getText().toString().trim();
        String stringkey = key.getText().toString().trim();
        String stringsecret = secret.getText().toString().trim();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(stringhost)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "所输内容为空，请确认后输入", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(stringkey)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "所输内容为空，请确认后输入", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(stringsecret)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "所输内容为空，请确认后输入", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        MainActivity.this. runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // refresh ui 的操作代码
                ArtemisConfig.host = stringhost;//"127.0.0.1:443"; // artemis网关服务器ip端口
                ArtemisConfig.appKey = stringkey;//"29180881";  // 秘钥appkey
                ArtemisConfig.appSecret = stringsecret;//"XO0wCAYGi4KV70ybjznx";// 秘钥appSecret

                /**
                 * STEP2：设置OpenAPI接口的上下文
                 */
                final String ARTEMIS_PATH = "/artemis";

                /**
                 * STEP3：设置接口的URI地址
                 */
                final String VechicleDataApi = ARTEMIS_PATH +"/api/fms/v3/human/findSnapHuman";
                Map<String,String> path = new HashMap<String,String>(2){
                    {
                        put("https://",VechicleDataApi);
                    }
                };

                /**
                 * STEP4：设置参数提交方式
                 */
                //String contentType = "application/json";

                /**
                 * STEP5：组装请求参数
                 */
                JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                try{
                    jsonBody.put("deviceCodes","-1");
                    jsonBody.put("sex",-1);
                    jsonBody.put("beginDate","2017-09-01 12:00:00");
                    jsonBody.put("endDate","2017-09-12 12:00:00");
                    jsonBody.put("similarityMin",0.1);
                    jsonBody.put("similarityMax",1);
                    jsonBody.put("picUrl", "http://10.33.44.61:6501/pic?=d82i649e*4ebi05f-646618-52c3ca0764e4cai5b1*=1d6s4*=6dpi*=1d3i4t2pe*m5i13=-1050e3-10z1cas=630bd1");
                    jsonBody.put("pageNo",1);
                    jsonBody.put("pageSize",12);
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    /*Message message = Message.obtain();
                    message.what = ERROR;*/
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "查询错误，请检查无误后输入", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                String body = jsonBody.toString();
                /**
                 * STEP6：调用接口
                 */
                String result = ArtemisHttpUtil.doPostStringArtemis(path,body,null,null,"application/json");// post请求application/json类型参数
                /*Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.what = SUCCESS;
                message.obj = result;*/
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "查询成功，请点击预览按钮", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "返回信息：" + result, LENGTH_LONG).show();
                FindURL fi = new FindURL();
                fi.setUrl(result);
            }
        });
    }
}


/**
 * 获取手机存储读写权限
 */
private void requestPermissions() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, (new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}), 10);
    }
}
```

}

The new EXCEPTION has happened:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hikvision.open.app, PID: 10719
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;)V in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes3.dex)
    at com.hikvision.artemis.sdk.util.HttpUtil.sslClient(HttpUtil.java:499)
    at com.hikvision.artemis.sdk.util.HttpUtil.wrapClient(HttpUtil.java:478)
    at com.hikvision.artemis.sdk.util.HttpUtil.httpPost(HttpUtil.java:178)
    at com.hikvision.artemis.sdk.Client.execute(Client.java:53)
    at com.hikvision.artemis.sdk.ArtemisHttpUtil.doPostStringArtemis(ArtemisHttpUtil.java:182)
    at com.hikvision.open.app.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:151)
    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6281)
    at com.hikvision.open.app.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:99)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I need help!!!PLEASE!!

Answer (score 0):

This error might arise when you try to update a view from a thread which you can't do. `new Thread()` class create a different thread, so android main thread won't allow update UI from other thread other than the main thread.  You'll need to use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) to update your view.

You can use runOnUiThread as follows:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {                     
        // your code to update the UI thread here               
    }
});
```

Comment: I have used the idea,code:   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {.........});     There is a new exception:    Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity

Comment: and I find it should be : MainActivity.this. runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

Comment: But those are not reasons.The new EXCEPTION: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hikvision.open.app, PID: 10719
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: